# Variational principle if coordinate transformation depends on fields

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, coordinate-systems, variational-principle, variational-calculus

Assume we have a Lagrangian that is given in terms of Lagrangian density.

$$ L = \int \mathcal{L} (\Phi,  \partial_{\mu}\Phi, x) d^N x $$

Also assume that $\Phi : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$ and is smooth and bijective. I am interested what happens to Lagrangian density, fields, their derivatives and equations of motion if I now consider change of coordinates to $y = \Phi(x)$.

Usually we have coordinate independent coordinate transformations. Also, I am not sure if there is an answer to this question because it seems to me that it is not well defined. Consider the following Lagrangian density.

$$ \mathcal{L} = \Phi(x) $$

It seems to me that in the new coordinates it will be given as just following.

$$ \mathcal{L} = y $$

Now there is no reference to fields (that are being varied) at all, so I think that equations of motions are not well defined anymore. Is that correct? Maybe that is not the case because now stress-energy tensor is not conserved and we have source terms in conservation laws that create correct equations of motions in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your $d x$ will now depend on $\Phi$ so  $L[\Phi]= \int y \frac{d\Phi^{-1} (y)}{dy} dy$.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good point. What about incompressible flow where determinant of Jacobian is one?